# Why has my tub spout diverter not dropping back down after use? (brand new installation)

Tags: shower, bathtub, downspout, spout, diverter

I installed a replacement tub spout with diverter and after about a week, the diverter doesn't always come back down after a shower. At first it dropped down right after a shower. Sometimes it happens hours later and sometimes it doesn't happen at all and when I turn the water on the showerhead immediately sprays water. Did I install the spout incorrectly? I can give more info if I haven't explained enough, but at this point I'm not sure at all what I did wrong.

Comment: Nothing is wrong other than the expectation that it will immediately drop on its own. One that leaks badly will do that. A new one that was well built will generally need you to push the knob you pulled up back down to drain in a timely manner. You've been trained by an old leaky one to expect otherwise.

Comment: If the diverter does not immediately drop when you turn off the valves, then push it down. You want the water in the shower piping to drain immediately so the tub will dry out as soon as possible. Over time the diverter mechanism will  "wear in" and will drop without having to be pushed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the faucets are turned off when you are finished showering the diverter will usually not drop by itself.  The diverter is held up by the column of water in the shower pipe. Once the column of water is reduced due to dripping of the diverter, the diverter stem will fall and reopen the spout to its normal position. How long that takes is dependent on how long it takes for the column of water in the shower pipe to fall. I usually just push down on the diverter actuator pin to release the shower pipe water.